# Nodemon runs multiple times on save when using babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, nodemon

I am using Nodemon and Babel 6. I have uninstalled Nodemon globally and have installed the latest version.

I have tried both of the following lines in my npm scripts:

```
"watch-new": "nodemon src/index.js --exec babel-node"
```

And

```
"watch-new": "nodemon src/index.js --exec babel -w src/ -d build/ --source-maps"
```

Changes in running babel seem to result in similar/identical nodemon-related mess-ups.

I started with a file that simply contained `console.log("Hello, World!");` then added a line after that statement that contained `console.log("Test");`. Saving (only once) the now two line file resulted in the following console output.

Adding either of the following to nodemon makes my program restart only once "--delay 2.5" or "-L" / "--legacyWatch"

Why is it running and reloading so many times?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've found that combinations of `nodemon`, `babel`, and other watcher type programs can often oddly interact. This type of "double run" outcome is pretty common. They work great when set up *just so*, but can be fragile.

That said, I do not understand your choice of command line arguments. I won't say they're wrong, but they don't correspond to the versions of `babel` that I have installed, or the documentation I'm using. There have been notable changes in the recommended ways to run Babel; not all the documentation on the internet is current and up-to-date with the latest approaches.

So rather than trying to debug what isn't working in your configuration, let me give you a configuration that *is* working for me.

First I installed Babel and its presets:

```bash
npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-es2015
```

Then the npm script in `package.json`:

```
"watch-new": "nodemon src --exec babel --presets es2015 -w src/ --out-dir build/ --source-maps"
```

(You can use other presets. I use just the big one, [ES2015](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015).)

I invoke `nodemon` against a source directory, not a single source file, in other to keep `babel` from nesting `src` under `build`; I assume you want individual `.js` files in `build`, not a `src` subdirectory. I also use the `--out-dir` option, which I understand to be correct (not `-d`).

Finally, run it:

```sh
npm run watch-new
```

These packages and that script invocation give correct, rerun-once-per-change behavior for me. If you want `node` to run the code immediately after transformation instead of saving it under `build/`, you can change `--exec babel` to `--exec babel-node` and remove the `--out-dir` specification.

As a final note, your question is tagged for ECMAscript-6. What was once called `es6` is now more officially called `es2015`. (See e.g. [this primer on the new version names](http://benmccormick.org/2015/09/14/es5-es6-es2016-es-next-whats-going-on-with-javascript-versioning/).) You're more likely to get the correct, up-to-date documentation if you search under the new `es2015` term.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I altered my npm scripts to match your new script. I end up with this output after making a single change. The highlighted line is where I was before altering the code and hitting save once. http://imgur.com/a/glcs1

Comment: If I remove the '-w src/' it just runs forever. Just an observation.

Comment: Adding either of the following to nodemon makes my program restart only once "--delay 2.5" or "-L" / "--legacyWatch"